# numpy: Creating a binary mask for a float array without allocating intermediate arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy float arrays of the same shape: `data` and `mask`. I want to populate the values of `mask` based on the values in `data`. When the value of an element in `data` is equal to one of the 'acceptable values' (see below), then the corresponding item in `mask` should be set to 1.0, otherwise it should be set to 0.0.

There are two possible scenarios:

1. acceptable values are all finite numbers
2. acceptable values are all finite numbers except 0.0

How can I achieve the above without any additional array allocations? For the first scenario I could use `numpy.isfinite` and the `out` argument. But what about the second scenario? `numpy.where` can't be used because it requires the creation of an intermediate array of indices. The only solution I can think of is to pass the numpy arrays to C and do it there. However, I was wondering if there is a pure numpy solution as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't a boolean mask is what you need?

Comment: Ideally, the `mask` array should be a float array as well (just clarified it in my post). Nevertheless, I don't expect the solution to vary a lot for `mask` arrays of different type.

Comment: Are the array creations really the bottleneck in your algorithm?

Comment: why?  are you hitting memory errors, or just hoping to save time?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using the `where` argument of the `np.isfinite` function to filter out elements equal to zero would achieve what you want? It is however slower than other options that use additional boolean arrays.

```
import numpy as np

# Dummy data
data = np.tile([0,np.inf,2,3,4,5], 10000000).astype(float)
mask = np.zeros_like(data, dtype = float)

# First scenario
np.isfinite(data, out = mask)

# Second scenario 
mask = np.zeros_like(data, dtype = float)
np.isfinite(data, out = mask, where = data != 0)
# Faster method using intermediate boolean arrays
np.bitwise_and(np.isfinite(data), data != 0, out = mask)
```

Comment: Both methods create a temporary `data != 0` array.

Comment: All approaches are faster if `mask` is `bool` dtype.

Comment: @hpaulj You are of course right. He specified a `float` dtype for the mask array in the question though.